# Ignore Parse Errors HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

Is it possible to ignore parse errors when using HTMLAgilityPack?

Comment: Would you be able to provide more context?  If you are attempting to 'fix' non Xhtml standard markup through the HtmlAgility Pack, I've provided an example on the question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446525/c-html-from-webbrowser-to-valid-xhtml/6446639#6446639

Comment: You might want to try out some of the HtmlDocument object's settings such as: - OptionCheckSyntax - OptionFixNestedTags - OptionOutputAsXml

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested by TrueWill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182564/389966), you may need to cleanse the HTML before trying to parse it with the HTMLAgilityPack.