# Ignoring parse errors with Html Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, pack

I'm trying to parse out a single page from YouTube... Which isn't really free of syntax errors. Html Agility Pack screams about these errors, and returns nothing in result.

http://codepaste.net/gh3hco

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but based on a [suggestion in their forum](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/258248) you can use HTML Tidy or [Tidy.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/) to clean the HTML first. Optionally, you could find the erroneous tags and remove them in a pre-process step.

Comment: Hi TrueWill, not to hijack things here, but I thought the reason people pick up the agility pack is to remove the need to hack out any tags in a pre-process step. I just spent 3 hours and itteratively wrote 6 pre-steps to try read some HTML using vanilla XML library before I found the htmlagilitypack. I want a rat-trap, not a mouse trap, is there anything self-contained out there?

Comment: @ConradB - Not that I know of. You could try posting a separate question for that; maybe someone else knows of one.