# C# HTML from WebBrowser to valid XHTML

Tags: c#, html, xhtml, browser, xmpp

So, we are using a webBrowser control in edit mode, to allow people to enter text, and then take that text and send it out to the server for everyone to see.  IE, it's an HTML input box.

The HTML output from that box isn't standard XHTML, given that it's just a webBrowser control, so i needed  a method to convert any bad HTML to XHTML.  I read up on SGML, and subsequently  have used:

```
private static string Html2Xml(string txtHtmlString)
    {
        var xhtml = new Sgml.SgmlReader();
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var w = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        xhtml.DocType = "HTML";
        xhtml.InputStream = new StringReader(txtHtmlString);

        while ((!xhtml.EOF))
        {
            w.WriteNode(xhtml, true);
        }

        w.Close();
        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

I basically pase HTML string to that method, and it returns 'suposed' proper XHTML.  However, it's not passing XHTML checks, and the data it returns is just a basic

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Format.  Thus, not proper XHTML.

So, how can i format that to actually output proper XHTML?  There isn't much on MindShares site for SGML documentation anymore, so not sure where to go from here.

Essentially, we need the HTML from the WebBrowser control, which isn't valid XHTML, to output to XHTML, so that we can attach it to an XMPP.msg.Html element (valid XHTML only).  If the system detects that any codes within the HTML is invalid, it marks the XMPP.msg.Html as blank, so i know the above method isn't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would reccomend using either something like TinyMCE or HtmlAgilityPack (available as a Nuget package or from codeplex).

TinyMCE allows users to perform a rich text edit with appropriate formatting controls, and will output the resultant Html.

HtmlAgilityPAck on the other hand is a library that will allow you to pass in the HtmlStream generated by your method, and output this as a valid Xhtml stream.

Rough example for working with this in the HtmlAgilityPAck as below:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(); 
var stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);

string input = "<html><body><p>This is some test test<ul><li>item 1<li>item2<</ul></body>";

var test = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
test.LoadHtml(input);
test.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
test.OptionCheckSyntax = true;
test.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

test.Save(stringWriter);

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I think the later may be better.  TinyMCE is nice, however, our application uses a ribbon control to handle all of the formatting commands, and shortcuts, etc.  So i dont want to replace the web browser with another element.  As to the HTMLAgilityPack, i have heard quite a few negative things about it converting invalid HTML.  So, i'm still uncertain, but will try it out.

Comment: I deployed HtmlAgilityPack for a project about a year ago, for a brief that involved taking non w3c standard Html and converting it into Xhtml.  From testing I can advise that although not perfect, the main issue we encountered was when we attempted to parse nested structures (such as list items within list items) where closing tags we're not used.  The end result was a valid DOM, but the underlying code had forced all of the tags to close only when they reached an element that they could not overlap.

Comment: Is HtmlAgilityPAck able to load up content as a string, instead of an actual file?  Our application is a chat application, and our input boxes just store the HTML as strings to parse:  `var html = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml` for example.  As it's not a document, i dont see a 'LoadString' or 'FromString' method for HtmlAgilityPAck.

Comment: Added an example of how to do this to my original answer.  Note that you can see some of the limitations with the example text I've provided, but the output should pass Xhtml validation checks.