# best way to store parsed html to out put in XML

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

What would be the best method (array, list, streamwriter or dictionary) to covert parsed html `innerText` and `innerhtml`(URL) so that it can be converted into XML.

This is the first program I am trying to write without help but I am stuck on this. I have not added any code into this question so I can learn how to do it on my own. Any advice which any one can give will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly, but why not store it as a `string`, then use `XElement.Parse()` to make it an XML object.

Comment: Use Html Agility Pack to parse the HTML, and then write it out as valid XHTML. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/  ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446525/c-sharp-html-from-webbrowser-to-valid-xhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` because HTML is rarely valid XML and you'll need to run it through a specialized parser to *attempt* getting as much of it as possible into XML form.

But assuming you are able to parse it, the intermediate between the string and XML would some sort of custom tree structure.  There is no built in tree structure in .NET but this is easy enough to create and the google will point you towards a billion tutorials.